# Hreflang for different subdomain for a different region speaking the same language

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, internationalization, hreflang, multi-subdomains

I have a website that has a different multilanguage domain such as `us`, `au`, `ie`, `eu`. but the language is the same, the only difference is the pricing of the product.

Would we run into duplicate content issues, and be penalized for it if we use `rel="alternate"` to link to such untranslated content, even if exists on a different language subdomain (specified in the alternate link)?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://classmanager.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href=" https://classmanager.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href=" https://classmanager.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://classmanager.com/us/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://classmanager.com/au/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ie" href="https://classmanager.com/ie/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://classmanager.com/eu/">
```